# C# Process: Using Pipes/File Descriptors

Tags: c#, process, pipe

I'm trying to connect to Chromium [in the same way Puppeteer does in NodeJS](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/lib/Launcher.js#L115).

This looks [super simple in NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_options_stdio). You add two more arguments to the stdio array and you have your pipes.

I'm not being able to implement the same logic in [Puppeteer-Sharp](https://github.com/kblok/puppeteer-sharp/). I spent some time reading many questions and answers here. I read about AnonymousPipeServerStream, but no joy.

This is one example I can't make it work:

```
AnonymousPipeServerStream streamReader = new AnonymousPipeServerStream(PipeDirection.In, HandleInheritability.Inheritable);
AnonymousPipeServerStream streamWriter = new AnonymousPipeServerStream(PipeDirection.Out, HandleInheritability.Inheritable);

var chromeProcess = new Process();
chromeProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
chromeProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
chromeProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "/.local-chromium/MacOS-536395/chrome-mac/Chromium.app/Contents/MacOS/Chromium";
chromeProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = 
    "--MANY-MANY-ARGUMENTS  " +
    "--remote-debugging-pipe  " +
    "--user-data-dir=/var/folders/0k/4qzqprl541b74ddz4wwj_ph40000gn/T/mz0trgjc.vlj " +
    "--no-sandbox " +
    "--disable-dev-shm-usage " + 
    streamReader.GetClientHandleAsString() +
    streamWriter.GetClientHandleAsString();

chromeProcess.Start();

streamReader.DisposeLocalCopyOfClientHandle();
streamWriter.DisposeLocalCopyOfClientHandle();

Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
{
    var reader = new StreamReader(streamReader);
    while (true)
    {
        var response = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(response))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(response);
        }
    }
});

Console.ReadLine();
```

Many examples show that you have to pass the `GetClientHandleAsString()` as an argument but I don't see how that can connect to processes.

This is a gist with [the full example](https://gist.github.com/kblok/e8964400d353048c5581edb151503469)

Answer (score 1):

The answers lies in starting the `Process` with a `ProcessStartInfo` that has `RedirectStandardInput`, `RedirectStandardOutput` and/or `RedirectStandardError` properties set and then using the `Process.StandardInput`, `Process.StandardOutput` and/or `Process.StandardError` properties to access the pipes.